# Computing multiple variable integral

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I have a 2 variable function named 'wig', and I have to take double integral of its absolute value with respect to the variables p and q. Then subtract 1 from the final answer and 3D plot it with q and p. In short, I have to compute $(\int\int dq dp  |(wig)|) - 1$ and then plot it. By using the following code, my integrals do not compute. Please tell me what is wrong with my code and how to correct it.

`wig`  `= (2*(7 - 20*I*Sqrt[2]*p - 24*p^2 - 20*Sqrt[2]*q + 48*I*p*q + 24*q^2 +  8*(-3 + 8*p^2 + 8*I*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) + 8*Sqrt[2]*q - 8*q^2)*Conjugate[p]^2 +  4*(-5*Sqrt[2] + 16*Sqrt[2]*p^2 + 28*q - 16*Sqrt[2]*q^2 - 4*I*p*(-7 + 8*Sqrt[2]*q))*Conjugate[q] +  8*(3 - 8*p^2 - 8*I*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) - 8*Sqrt[2]*q + 8*q^2)*Conjugate[q]^2 +  4*Conjugate[p]*(-16*I*Sqrt[2]*p^2 - 4*p*(-7 + 8*Sqrt[2]*q) + I*(5*Sqrt[2] - 28*q + 16*Sqrt[2]*q^2) -  4*(-8*I*p^2 + 8*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) + I*(3 - 8*Sqrt[2]*q + 8*q^2))*Conjugate[q])))/ (E^(2*Abs[-(1/Sqrt[2]) + I*p + q]^2)*(3*Pi*(Sqrt[2] - 4*I*p - 4*q)* (Sqrt[2] + 4*I*Conjugate[p] - 4*Conjugate[q])))`

intofwig = Integrate[Abs[wig], q]

doubint = Integrate[intofwig, p]

delta = Solve[doubint - 1]

Plot3D[delta, {q, - 10 , 5}, {p, -10, 5}, PlotRange -> All]

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Also, I see no `wig` defined anywhere. It looks like you copied half the cell or something. Try again.

Comment: Oops let me fix that

Comment: I have tried to fix it. If I put it in a code block, 'wig' does not appear I don't know why.

Comment: No. You still have syntax errors. `Ipq` should be `I*pq` and `ISqrt[2]` should be `I*Sqrt[2]` and `Ip` should be `I*p` and `IConjugate[p]` should be `I*Conjugate[p]` and so on. Simply convert the code to input form and copy/paste that. All your `I` are for some reason stuck to the letters next to them.

Comment: `Thanks. I copied the input form. Hope it's fine now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wig = (2*(7 - 20*I*Sqrt[2]*p - 24*p^2 - 20*Sqrt[2]*q + 48*I*p*q + 
      24*q^2 + 
      8*(-3 + 8*p^2 + 8*I*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) + 8*Sqrt[2]*q - 8*q^2)*
       Conjugate[p]^2 + 
      4*(-5*Sqrt[2] + 16*Sqrt[2]*p^2 + 28*q - 16*Sqrt[2]*q^2 - 
         4*I*p*(-7 + 8*Sqrt[2]*q))*Conjugate[q] + 
      8*(3 - 8*p^2 - 8*I*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) - 8*Sqrt[2]*q + 8*q^2)*
       Conjugate[q]^2 + 
      4*Conjugate[
        p]*(-16*I*Sqrt[2]*p^2 - 4*p*(-7 + 8*Sqrt[2]*q) + 
         I*(5*Sqrt[2] - 28*q + 16*Sqrt[2]*q^2) - 
         4*(-8*I*p^2 + 8*p*(Sqrt[2] - 2*q) + 
            I*(3 - 8*Sqrt[2]*q + 8*q^2))*Conjugate[q])))/(E^(2*
       Abs[-(1/Sqrt[2]) + I*p + q]^2)*(3*
      Pi*(Sqrt[2] - 4*I*p - 4*q)*(Sqrt[2] + 4*I*Conjugate[p] - 
        4*Conjugate[q])));

 abs = Simplify@ComplexExpand@Abs[wig];
 intofwig = Integrate[abs, q]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 doubint = Integrate[intofwig, p]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above gets you the integral. I do not know what you are solving for what you type

```
delta = Solve[doubint - 1]
```

But I think you can take it from here since now the integrals evaluate.

May be you meant this?

```
delta=doubint-1
Plot3D[delta,{p,-1,1},{q,-1,1},AxesLabel->{"p","q"},
     PlotLabel->"my nice plot in 3D",BaseStyle->14]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

V 13.3 on windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works.

Comment: Yeah I am getting a bit different plot. Perhaps the reason is I am using the PlotRange-> All command. I am actually computing the negative region in the wigner function

Comment: @Anaya  Adding `PlotRange->All` does not change the plot for me. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qYxD.png)  I am using V 13.3  May be you can post screen shot of the what you did showing the plot, starting from clean kernel.

Comment: My bad! I was actually using different values for 'q' and 'p'. Using your values, I got the same plot.